# Elastic search: Bucket aggregation uniform width bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a field names `price`("type": "long").
My requirement is to create an equal-sized bucket for the price range and get the count of docs for each range.

Eg: If the min value of `price` is 0 & max value of `price` is 100, I want 10 equal-sized buckets (0-10, 10-20,...,90-100), and a count of docs in each bucket. For range not having any docs should return 0.

**Findings**:

- [Range Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation), But for this, we have to provide the Range manually,
- [Histogram Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation), for this we have to provide Interval
- [Variable width histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-variablewidthhistogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-variablewidthhistogram-aggregation), not reliable as the width is not uniform.

For both Range and Histogram bucket aggregation, I will have to make 2 calls, first to get min & max values of `price`, then compute the Interval, and then pass the computed value to
Range/Histogram bucket aggregation.

Is there any way I can combine both in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

In Histogram, you will have to provide the interval yes, but you can calcuate it in the same call. :D

Initally you can calculate interval with `max_value` and `min_value`, but you will still need to pass them:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "price_range": {
            "histogram": {
                "field": "price",
                "interval": (max_value - min_value) / 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "count": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's go another step and find them in the same call which should answer your question:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "min_price": {
            "min": {
                "field": "price"
            }
        },
        "max_price": {
            "max": {
                "field": "price"
            }
        },
        "price_range": {
            "histogram": {
                "field": "price",
                "interval": (max_price - min_price) / 10,
                "min_doc_count": 0
            },
            "aggs": {
                "count": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In the second query, I have added another parameter under histogram. By default, histogram aggregation does not return the empty buckets, so you will have to set `min_doc_count: 0` to include those bucket in the result because you wanted ranges even with 0 doc count.

Comment: In ElasticSearch Devtools, the single query command looks invalid. I do not accept `min_price` and `max_price` query variables.
Error: `Unexpected character (`